# How do I make a full page width dropdown when you click the :hover of the burger menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I make a full page width drop-down appear when the burger menu is clicked but still keep the close function(X). (Dropdown menu and the close burger menu transition when clicked)

Below is the JS functions for the burger menu animations. Transition with hover and close when clicked.

```js
 $("#wrapper").hover(function() {
    $(".menu").toggleClass("transition");
  });

$("#wrapper").click(function() {
  $(".transition").toggleClass("close");
});
```

Below is the css to transition the burger menu when hovered and closed functions are applied.

```css
<style>
.burgerMenu-right {
    font-family: 'Circe Rounded', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
    display: inline;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 8px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: black;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
  right: 4%;
}

.main-item {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}



.line {
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: all cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.28, 1.54) 0.32s;
  background: black;
}

.line01 {
  top: 33.3%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.line02 {
  top: 66.6%;
  width: 65%;
  right: 0;
}

.menu:hover .line01 {
  width: 65%;
}

.menu:hover .line02 {
  width: 100%;
  top: 66%;
}

.menu.close .line01 {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 49%;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu.close .line02 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 49%;
  width: 100%;
}

</style>
```

Below is the html for the burger menu....

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="main-item menu">
    <span class="line line01"></span>
    <span class="line line02"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: the code for your hamburger is nice and works well, however we have no attempt for any full-page styles or dropdown here, and thus no specific problem to solve, so that it more or less ends in a code writing request, even with your current efforts.

Comment: make a fiddle on jsfiddle.net and show us your attempt

Comment: Sure thing, I will upload my attempt. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use below code

```js
 $(document).ready(function($) {

$(".menu").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("transition close");
   $(".down-bg").slideToggle();
})
});
```

```css
.burgerMenu-right {
    font-family: 'Circe Rounded', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
    display: inline;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 8px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: black;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
  right: 4%;
}

.main-item {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 10
}



.line {
  position: absolute;
  height: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
  transition: all cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.28, 1.54) 0.32s;
  background: black;
}

.line01 {
  top: 33.3%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.line02 {
  top: 66.6%;
  width: 65%;
  right: 0;
}

.menu:hover .line01 {
  width: 65%;
}

.menu:hover .line02 {
  width: 100%;
  top: 66%;
}

.menu.close .line01 {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 49%;
  width: 100%;
}

.menu.close .line02 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 49%;
  width: 100%;
}
.down-bg{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="main-item menu">
    <span class="line line01"></span>
    <span class="line line02"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="down-bg"></div>
</div>
```